# Return unique digits of a time format string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Need to create a regex pattern that will return unique digits before or after a : symbol, using String.match. It should only return the digit, not the : symbol. PS: I know there is other (maybe easier) ways to do this, but I want to use regex for learning purposes

```
let s;
let regex = /(^\d:)(:\d$)/g // I tried this, off course it didn't work

s = '12:34'
s.match(regex) // return null

s = '1:34'
s.match(regex) // return [1]

s = '12:4'
s.match(regex) // return [4]

s = '1:4'
s.match(regex) // return [1,4]
```

Comment: `/^(\d+):(\d+)$/`.  No point to `g`, you're matching the entire text

Comment: It is just two capture groups with : in the middle....

Comment: I know they are probably not real examples, but just in case they are, you can also use `.split(':')` to have the same result.

Comment: It looks like even `let regex = /\b\d\b/g` works for you. ES5 compliant, no lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe that would incorrectly match '2 3', but not '12:34'

Comment: As it is now, `(^\d:)(:\d$)` matches none of your sample strings.

Comment: You don't need lookbehinds to do this. Use `^(?=.*\d)(\d?):(\d?)$` and group 1 and/or group 2 contains the left/right single digits.

Comment: @sln this pattern works only when both sides have 1 digit only.

Comment: @MichelCurti - That's a fine observation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
let regex = /(((?<=:)\d(?!\d))|((?<!\d)\d(?=:)))/g
```

This will match the patterns you want!

Here's a [reference](https://regex101.com/r/0sW4FZ/1) for Regex.

```js
let s;
let regex = /(((?<=:)\d(?!\d))|((?<!\d)\d(?=:)))/g

s = '12:34'
console.log(s.match(regex)) // return null

s = '1:34'
console.log(s.match(regex)) // return [1]

s = '12:4'
console.log(s.match(regex)) // return [4]

s = '1:4'
console.log(s.match(regex)) // return [1,4]
```

Comment: So many people molested your answer, so I'll just say with high confidence, look behind assertions aren't supported in EcmaScript5. Why is this the accepted answer ?

Comment: @sln Because it is 2019, and lookbehinds are supported since ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  - I don't see them supported anywhere, can you give me a test site that supports JS lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @sln Open a Chrome console and paste `"a1b".match(/(?<=a)\d(?=b)/g)` there.

Comment: I don't do Chrome @WiktorStribiżew, I use IE11. But, show an online JS regex test site that supports lookbehind assertions. This is not a browser issue for now.

Comment: @sln Use Chrome and go to http://regex101.com and you may use lookbehinds there. You may benefit a lot if you switch to Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work like that @WiktorStribiżew, Regex101.com site doesn't use your browser to do regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Create a link that I may see the test with.

Comment: @sln I believe you know how to use http://regex101.com. Just paste `a1b` and use `(?<=a)\d(?=b)` regex. In any ECMAScript 2018 compliant browser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Ok, I did that, here you go https://imgur.com/v8Oy7S5

Comment: @sln You seem to miss one very important bit: **use Chrome**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I can't afford Chrome, I'd have to triple the size of my hosts file. Either way, I don't believe you. A test site has to be consistent if it gives out permalinks which are by nature fixed to the use of a version. A snapshot of the current version when the link is created is assumed, not browser dependent. Maybe you never heard of emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Example done in JavaScript.  The 2nd regex is the most simple, it matches a digit followed by a colon, followed by a digit (you could use this with the `g` flag if there is more than one occurrence in your text).

1st regex matches the entire string and MAY have one or more characters before the 1st digit and one or more characters after the 2nd one.  This will only capture one occurrence for the entire string.

```js
let regex1 = /^.*(\d):(\d).*$/;
let regex2 = /(\d):(\d)/;

console.log("Make sure the entire string only contains one instance");
['12:34', '1:34', '12:4', '1:4' ].forEach( (s) => console.log(s.match(regex1) ));
console.log("Match the first instance found");
['12:34', '1:34', '12:4', '1:4' ].forEach( (s) => console.log(s.match(regex2) ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what do you mean by "unique".
But if you want to just get numbers then you can use `+` or `*` quantifiers.

`/^(\d+):(\d+)$/`

Comment: Thank you. I mean that it matches only if there is only one digit after or before the : (as you can see in the examples)

Comment: @MichelCurti You're missing the additional **+**. (i.e. `\d+`, not `\d`).  Changes it from "match a single digit" (in your code) to "match one or more digits".  This answer could do more to explain the difference.

Comment: @Tibrogargan but I want to match only one digit, not more. Can you post an answer explaning how the pattern should be?

Comment: @MichelCurti Your question does not explain this.   Would you please edit your question and clarify the requirements?  Thanks